# MySQL select rows where given date lies between the dates stored in table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Suppose I have some data like:

```
id  status activity_date
--- ------ -------------
101   R     2014-01-12
101   Mt    2014-04-27 
101   R     2014-05-18
102   R     2014-02-19
```

Note that for rows with id = 101 we have activity between 2014-01-12 to 2014-04-26 and 2014-05-18 to current date.

Now I need to select that data where status = 'R' and the date is the most current date as of a given date, e.g. if I search for 2014-02-02, I would find the status row created on 2014-01-12, because that was the status that was still valid at the time for entity ID 101.

Comment: Do you specifically want to select the activity date `2014-02-02` and no other values?

Comment: @Scott, I want to select data which status R(running) on the selected date like '2014-02-02'

Comment: This is a common problem in Data Warehousing and known as a Kimball Slowly Changing Dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

**Step 1:** Convert the start and end date rows into columns. For this, you must join the table with itself based on this criteria:

```sql
SELECT
    dates_fr.id,
    dates_fr.activity_date AS date_fr,
    MIN(dates_to.activity_date) AS date_to
FROM test AS dates_fr
LEFT JOIN test AS dates_to ON 
    dates_to.id = dates_fr.id AND
    dates_to.status = 'Mt' AND
    dates_to.activity_date > dates_fr.activity_date
WHERE dates_fr.status = 'R'
GROUP BY dates_fr.id, dates_fr.activity_date
```

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | date_fr    | date_to    |
+------+------------+------------+
|  101 | 2014-01-12 | 2014-04-27 |
|  101 | 2014-05-18 | NULL       |
|  102 | 2014-02-19 | NULL       |
+------+------------+------------+
```

**Step 2:** The rest is simple. Wrap the query inside another query and use appropriate where clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        dates_fr.id,
        dates_fr.activity_date AS date_fr,
        MIN(dates_to.activity_date) AS date_to
    FROM test AS dates_fr
    LEFT JOIN test AS dates_to ON 
        dates_to.id = dates_fr.id AND
        dates_to.status = 'Mt' AND
        dates_to.activity_date > dates_fr.activity_date
    WHERE dates_fr.status = 'R'
    GROUP BY dates_fr.id, dates_fr.activity_date
) AS temp WHERE '2014-02-02' >= temp.date_fr and ('2014-02-02' < temp.date_to OR temp.date_to IS NULL)
```

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | date_fr    | date_to    |
+------+------------+------------+
|  101 | 2014-01-12 | 2014-04-27 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46983/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select id, status, activity_date 
from TABLE 
where status = "R" and activity_date = "2014-02-02"
```

where TABLE is name of your table

Comment: May as well just use `SELECT *` rather than name all of his attributes individually

Comment: yes, but if somebody asks of simple things I try to show it as simple as possible...Maybe he will read it...

Comment: I can not select it activity_date = "2014-02-02" , because it is the date range. Ex. 101 product is R(running) from (2014-01-12 to  2014-04-26) and also (2014-05-18 to till today). So how can select this product was running on the  "2014-02-02"

Comment: I don't understand why you've directed that at me

Comment: I also dont understant what you mean.  Do you want to select only with id = 101?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need following ans

```
SELECT id,MAX(CAST(ACTIVITY_DATE AS date),MIN(CAST (ACTIVITY_DATE AS date)  
FROM Table_Name WHERE CAST('2014-02-02' AS date)
BETWEEN  MIN(CAST (ACTIVITY_DATE AS date) AND MAX(CAST(ACTIVITY_DATE AS date) 
 AND Status='R'
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable 
where status='R' and activity_date= '2014-02-02'
```

Comment: Read OP's comment below the question.

Comment: @SalmanA:- `I want to select data which status R(running) on the selected date like '2014-02-02'` If I take this then the query which I posted seems correct. But I think OP is still not making it clear as to what s/he is looking for specially the line in question `**which** activity_date 2014-02-02`

Comment: The [description in bold](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32245853/2) makes it somewhat clear that OP is talking about date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query to effectively give you the most status as of a date, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id, 
    substr(max(concat(activity_date, status)),11) as status,
    max(activity_date) as activity_date
FROM table
WHERE activity_date <= '2014-02-02'
GROUP by id;
```

Then, similar to Salman's answer, you can use this result inside another query and look for all those results with a status of 'R'

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT
        id,
        substr(max(concat(activity_date, status)),11) as status,
        max(activity_date) as activity_date
    FROM table
    WHERE activity_date <= '2014-02-02'
    GROUP by id
) AS temp WHERE temp.status = 'R';
```

**Edit**: Rather than use the questionable method of sorting the statuses, you could identify the relevant maximum record with a sub-query, so the original query would become

```
SELECT join1.* FROM table AS join1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, max(activity_date) as max_activity_date
    FROM table
    WHERE activity_date < '2014-02-02'
    GROUP BY id
) AS join2
ON join1.id = join2.id AND join1.activity_date = join2.max_activity_date;
```

and the full query

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT join1.* FROM table AS join1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, max(activity_date) as max_activity_date
        FROM table
        WHERE activity_date < '2014-02-02'
        GROUP BY id
    ) AS join2
    ON join1.id = join2.id AND join1.activity_date = join2.max_activity_date
) AS temp WHERE temp.status = 'R';
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM your_relation
WHERE status='R'
AND activity_data="2014-02-02"
```

Answer (score -1):

I completely agree with Salman's response, the table could be designed in a fashion that allows for greater query accuracy and extensibility. However, the question asked, with regards to a query selecting information based on status and date range can be expressed as.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
WHERE ((status = 'R')
AND ((activity_date BETWEEN '2014-01-12' AND '2014-04-26')
OR activity_date  > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-05-17')))
```

This will select all data with a status of 'R' and will use the BETWEEN operator for the range desired; moreover, the conversion of the final operator is because the expression is evaluated as a mathematical expression and requires explicit conversion.